# matplotlib error: ValueError: 'home_event' is not a valid value for signal

Tags: python, matplotlib

today I upgraded my matplotlib to version 3.6.0 and my code crashed with this error:

```
ValueError: 'home_event' is not a valid value for signal; supported values are 'resize_event', 'draw_event', 'key_press_event', 'key_release_event', 'button_press_event', 'button_release_event', 'scroll_event', 'motion_notify_event', 'pick_event', 'figure_enter_event', 'figure_leave_event', 'axes_enter_event', 'axes_leave_event', 'close_event'
```

I found that the reason is the line: `self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('home_event', self.on_home)`.

After searching on matplotlib changelog I found that the problem is:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#callbackregistry-raises-on-unknown-signals

Answer (score 1):

For now, my recommendation is to downgrade matplotlib to version 3.5.3: `pip install "matplotlib<3.6.0"`

I will add a better solution when I will find one.